# Reading XML file in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-xml, readfile

I have a questions.xml file which has a list of questions for my quiz, and I'm trying to read this into a question bank in my program.  I have written the following method:

```
// Creates the QuestionBank according to user requirements
public ArrayList<Question> createQuestionBank(String diff) {
    int eventType = -1;
    boolean FoundQuestions = false;
    QuestionBank = new ArrayList<Question>();

    // Find Question records from XML
    System.out.println("check 1");
    while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {   // Keep reading until the end of the xml file
        System.out.println("check 2");
        if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) { 
            System.out.println("check 3");
            String Name = questionList.getName();
            if (Name.equals("question")){   // Check whether the tag found is the one for question
                System.out.println("check 4");
                // Check difficulty of question
                String diffCheck = questionList.getAttributeValue(null, "difficulty");
                if (diff.equals("Any") || diff.equals(diffCheck)){
                    FoundQuestions = true;
                    System.out.println("check 5");
                    createandaddquestion();
                    System.out.println("check 6");
                }
            }
            try {
                eventType = questionList.next();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return QuestionBank;
}
```

I set some output statements to identify where my program was going wrong.  The method outputs an endless cycle of check2 and never progresses to check 3, so is getting stuck at the statement:

```
if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG)
```

I have adapted some code which I have found elsewhere and do not entirely understand what is happening.  My understanding is that this statement finds the start part of a tag which I then progress to check whether this is the question tag which signifies the start of my question entry; what exactly is eventType though?  Apparently it is an integer, but why does the XMLResourceParser.START_TAG return an integer when a tag is found?  Surely it would make more sense to be a boolean?  From the above post I don't think I need to stress that I am very new to android so please be patient!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 Pearsonartphoto is probably right in his assumption. As an extra my experience is that using a SAX parser is much much more efficient on Android - at least in the early versions. 20 seconds to parse a file vs. less than a second.

Comment: @MarkGjøl Thanks Mark!  I'm quite concerned about how stable my final program will be so I will definitely be looking into the SAX parser now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that eventType is never getting updated. I don't know enough about the specifics of XML parsing, but it seems that eventType needs to be updated, or else you will be stuck in an infinite loop, as you are currently being stuck. I'm guessing from looking at your code that you want to move this code down one set of brackets:

```
        try {
            eventType = questionList.next();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

That will make sure it is called during every loop of the while() command.

Comment: Thanks man!  Worked perfectly after that!  You don't happen to know what exactly eventType is do you?  I didn't really understand the android developers website.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Sax parser and it works great:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Answer (score 0):

You might find the Xerces2 API to be useful as well. It implements SAX and DOM parsing. http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/